# First run after install from Google Play

Tags: trusted-web-activity, twa

I prepare apk and upload to Google Play. 
When I first run it on phone I receive message: Open in Chrome and button - OK. Can I hide this message on first run? I cannot find solution for that.

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of what's happening?

Comment: Do you mean the "Running in Chrome" message? https://crbug.com/981323

Comment: when i open an app in phone a have message: Open in Chrome [OK], Open in Brave [OK]
Look at screenshot, on the bottom I have: Open in Brave [OK] or Open in Chrome [OK]. It is only in first run, when i clicked OK, the next run will be ok

https://www.ibard.com/d/38a5508d4044a4dc3639c584a2e53722864b077d

Comment: @andreban, yes, this is the issue -> https://crbug.com/981323

Comment: Cool. Posted as an answer. Could you accept it?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to remove the `Running in Chrome` message. Improvements on how the information is displayed to users is being discussed in this bug: crbug.com/981323